# Can I import a list of events into Google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, import

I'd like to import a list of events into a Google Calendar in bulk (not using WebCal, just a plain old text file).

Can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

From the Google Calendar site go to settings and then to the "Calendars" tab. About half way down the page under your list of current calendars is an "import calendar" link. You can pull in calendar data in iCal or CSV formats.

See [Google's help page](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=34573&hl=en) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find this just by looking around but this is exactly what I wanted.